# Recursion in a tailored map function - don't understand the program flow

Tags: python, tail-recursion, iterable-unpacking

I am learning tail recursion and don't understand the flow of this example.
I am using VSCode debugger and don't understand why when the program reaches `return[f(arg), *result]` it goes to `result = my_map(f, rest)` line and `arg` becomes `2`

(attached picture [VSCode Debugger - step I don't understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDwOH.png)).

```py
def my_map(f, iterable):
    try:
        arg, *rest = iterable
    except ValueError:
        return []
    result = my_map(f, rest)
    return[f(arg), *result]

print(my_map(lambda x: x+10, [1,2,3]))
```

I am not used to the unpack operator (*) so maybe I am missing something there.

Since `arg` was `3` and `result` was `[]`, I was just expecting the `return` to return a list like `[3,[]]`.

Title EDITED: it is not tail recursion since the recursion isn't the last thing the function does.- Thanks > https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar

EDITED: more explanation about what I don't understand:
First, I get everything until result becomes an empty list.
[looping through try-except block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/049O6.png)
Then, we get into return [f(arg),*result]
There is where I don't understand why the execution (seeing it from the debugger) goes back to the previous line (result). So if someone could explain me what is happening from that point on...

Comment: This isn't tail recursion, since the recursion isn't the last thing the function does.

Comment: Why don't you understand? `rest` is the list `[2, 3]` because of the unpacking. Since `args` is the first element of `iterable`, and `iterable == [2, 3]`, `arg` is `2`.

Comment: It seems like you don't understand recursion in general. Each nested call to the function has its own instances of all the local variables.

Comment: with `arg, *rest = [1,2,3]` you end up with `arg` as `1` and `rest` as `[2,3]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar  than you for the reply.
1.- I didn't know that it's not tail recursion, thanks for pointing it out. Then it is just recursion right? in line 6 of the code.

Comment: That's really bad code. Probably someone trying to be fancy with the unpack operator but the try/catch could be replaced with a one liner `if not iterable: return []` and then using iterable[0] and iterable[1:] in place of arg and rest.

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766736/how-does-return-statement-with-recursion-calls-hold-intermediate-values-in-pytho) help at all?

Comment: @Barmar you were right. That has been my introduction to recursion. I had no idea what I was dealing with. Thanks for letting me know that about variables. I watched a video in youtube and explained what you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand the flow I had 1st to  watch this ideal video about recursion https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfBqVVKg4GE
Then I understood that it was not a good example to understand recursion at all...

So based on that, I did the map of the call stack status in the same fashion it is done in the video. See picture:
[Call stack status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Akz68.png)

Hope it helps

Comment: I put a small screenshot of VSCode at the bottom right corner of the picture, in which we can see that VSCode in debugger mode actually shows the changes in the call stack.